# What is the direction of friction when velocity and acceleration are opposite to each other?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction

> Suppose a body has a velocity $v$ while a force $ma$ acts on it in the opposite direction. Here $m$ is the mass of the body and $a$ is the acceleration imparted to the body by this force. If the coefficient of friction is $u$, in which direction will friction act and will it be static or kinetic? What will be it's magnitude?

Here is what I thought. First kinetic friction will act in the same direction as the force. When $v$ becomes $0$, then static friction will act in the initial direction of $v$, if it is greater than $ma$, or else the direction of kinetic friction will be opposite to the force. Is this right?

Comment: Is "force $ma$" (let's call it $F_e$) and friction $F_f$ different forces? Because, if so, this extra external force $F_e$ cannot be $ma$, since that's the value (according to Newton's 2nd law) of the **resultant force** $F_r=F_e+F_f$ on the body.

Comment: How is the object moving? Is it sliding or rolling?

Comment: @stafusa, the force ma is one of the forces acting on the body, not the net force. That is what I meant in the question.

Comment: But then it's a very misleading "name", since $a$ in general **will not be** the acceleration of the body: because Newton's 2nd law states that $ma=F_\text{resultant}$.

Comment: Impossible to answer with the information given.

Comment: That Roman letter $u$ should probably be the Greek letter $\mu$...

Comment: @stafusa, okay so I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, yes, there is kinetic friction while it moves, and static friction when reaching $v=0$.

But you cannot assume kinetic friction to act the same way as the force.

- **Kinetic friction** doesn't care *how* the objects slide over each other. It doesn't care if it speeds up or slows down this sliding. Kinetic friction just wants to *stop* the sliding. So it always pulls in the way that stops the sliding - which is opposite to the (relative) velocity **at all times**. Regardless of acceleration. Regardless of any forces acting.

Kinetic friction **always acts against the (relative) velocity** with a magnitude of $f_k=u_k n$.

- **Static friction** *also* only wants to prevent sliding. But in contrast to before, static friction is *variable* and will hold back just as much as it has to - in the direction it has to - to prevent sliding. So static friction always holds back against whatever else tries to push and cause sliding. In other words, static friction always holds back **opposite to the other forces**.

Static friction **always acts against the (sum of) other forces** but has an **unknown magnitude** (we only have a formula for the *maximum* value it can take: $f_s\leq u_sn$. We don't necessarily know, if this value is reached or not.)