# Calculate the kinetic friction velocity vector from the kinetic friction force in a simulation

Tags: kinematics, friction, simulations, drag

I am doing (programming) a simple kinematic 2D simulation on blocks. The idea is that the block will have a force applied.

1) From the force and mass I calculate the the acceleration vector (will show just the *x* dimension, the *y* dimension is the same):

```
//F = m * a, a = F / m
block.acceleration.x = block.force.x / block.mass;
```

2) From the simulation elapsed time *dt* and acceleration I update the velocity vector:

```
block.velocity.x = block.velocity.x + block.acceleration.x * dt;
```

3) From the velocity and time *dt* I update the position:

```
block.position.x = block.position.x + block.velocity.x * dt;
```

Assuming this is correct (but please correct me if I am mistaken) my problem is when I try to simulate the kinetic friction force of magnitude `Fk = uk * m * g` (where *uk* is the friction coefficient and the normal is equal to the weight (`m * g`).

Since kinetic friction is referred as a *force*, my idea was take this force (actually just its magnitude) and go through the same process as above: force -> acceleration -> velocity. Then remove this velocity magnitude from the `block.velocity` taking care never to "invert" the `block.velocity` vector.

```
//calculate the force (kinetic friction magnitude)
kinetic_friction_force = kinetic_friction_coefficient * block_mass * g;
kinetic_friction_acceleration = kinetic_friction_force / block.mass; //a = F / m
```

And I stop here because I believe this does not make sense. In this last step I am cancelling out block.mass and that does not look correct.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The "F" in "F=ma" should always be the net-force.

So, assuming one-dimensional motion with a push force and a kinetic friction force,
then (assuming  `velocity.x > 0` ),

`block.velocity.x = block.velocity.x + ( (block.push.x  - uk*m*g )/m ) * dt;`

More generally, instead of “just the minus-sign”,
it would be better to use "minus the sign of `velocity.x` ".
Even better is to use dot-products to handle general motion on the plane.

Comment: I think that your formula is the same as mine. The part: `(block.push.x - uk*m*g)/m` is equivalent to `block.push.x/m - (uk*m*g)/m` so in the friction part the mass gets cancelled out and thus my doubt.

Comment: In this special case (and possibly other special cases), yes, the equations may agree. However, the physics of Newton's second law is that a=F_net/m. There is only one acceleration vector determined by the net-force... and only one velocity-vector determined by the acceleration. It is a physics misconception that each force in a free body diagram leads to its own acceleration.

Comment: Maybe the kinetic friction force is something else. If I do the simulation using this formula the friction won't be affected by the mass, which doesn't make sense. It looks that I should use the `uk*m*g` part directly on the [velocity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/355555/234481): _Kinetic friction **always acts against the (relative) velocity** with a magnitude of_ `fk=uk*n`.